# What are loop devices?

Tags: linux, loopback

[How to Install Ubuntu on Android!](http://androlinux.com/android-ubuntu-development/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-android/) states "your Android OS must support loop devices".  What is a loop device?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [Wikipedia page on loop devices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_device) explains this pretty well. It's basically a "pseudo-device" (i.e. a device which doesn't exist physically) that allows a file to be treated as a block device (for example, a hard drive).

You need support for it because the Ubuntu system is stored as a .img file, which is essentially created to be a file representation of a filesystem or disk partition. By mounting it on a loop device you can access the file as though it really was a whole filesystem, thus creating a sort of "virtual" partition (or disk) for Ubuntu to live on.

Answer (score 4):

> In Unix-like operating systems, a loop device, vnd (vnode disk), or lofi (loopback file interface) is a pseudo-device that makes a file accessible as a block device.

<sub>http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_device</sub>

Basically, it allows you to make your phone think that an image file is a separate storage area/device.